# Help writing an algorithm for indexing/parsing a limited chunk of data on cron run

Tags: php, algorithm, parsing, drupal, cron

Here's the situation. I am scrapping a website to get the data from it's articles using a robots page supplied by that website (list of URLs pointing to every article that's posted on the site). So far, I do a database merge to 'upsert' the URLs into my table. I know that each scrapping run will take a good while cause there's over 1400 articles to parse. I need to write an algorithm that will only do a small chunk of the jobs on cron at a time so it doesn't overload my server, etc.

Edit: I think I should mention that I'm using drupal 7. Also, this has to be an ongoing script that happens over time, I'm not so worried about the time it takes for the initial fill of the database. The robots page is dynamic, URLs get added there periodically as articles are added. I'm using hook_cron() currently for this, but I'm open to better methods if there's something better than that for doing it.

Comment: How about simply waiting 60 seconds between each article? You'll be done in about a day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Drupal queue operations API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.queue.inc/group/queue/7) to enqueue each page to scrap as queue item. You can, but are not required, declare your queue as cron-executed. Drupal will then take cares of executing as much queue item at each [cron run](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_cron_run/7) without reaching the queue declared maximum execution time.

See [aggregator_cron](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--aggregator--aggregator.module/function/aggregator_cron/7) for an example of item en-queuing. And [`aggregator_cron_queue_info`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--aggregator--aggregator.module/function/aggregator_cron_queue_info/7) for the declaration that will let Drupal process these queued items during its cron.

If queue processing during normal Drupal cron is an issue, you can process your queue independently with the help of modules like [Waiting Queue](http://drupal.org/project/waiting_queue) or [Beanstalkd integration](http://drupal.org/project/beanstalkd).

Comment: This seems like the best option. Thanks!

Comment: I'm in the middle of implementing this, and so far so good. One issue I'm having is that adding it doesn't prevent duplicate queue entries. I can't seem to figure out how to implement that. How can I check if an item already exists in the queue?

Comment: You need to maintain the information about already enqueued item yourself in the DB. For instance, aggregator_cron add a timestamp which is cleared by aggregator_refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the http overhead of fetching each article will vastly outweigh the overhead of doing the database operations. Just don't fetch too many articles in parallel and you should be fine. Most webmasters frown on scrapers, especially when they're doing 10, 20, 500+ parallel fetches.

Comment: I knew that part already, the http overhead is pretty massive. We're at the point where this is kind-of our only option to get this to work (too complicated to explain the reasoning for doing it this way).

Comment: Split the job up into multiple chunks and fire up a script to process each of those chunks independently. script #1 gets urls 1-50, #2 gets 51-100, etc... Keep the number of scripts low (5 maybe). That'll cut the fetch time down to 20% (theoretically) of what it would'v been with just a single script fetching the urls serially.

Answer (score 0):

So, you already have the urls in your database.  Have a status column in that table - scraped or not.  The cron can kick off every so often grabbing the next url that has not been scraped from the table and marking it as scraped.